# Java Как исправить ошибку несовместимости версий библиотек?

Tags: java, maven, build, дерево

В проекте я обрабатываю файл с помощью Apache Tika. На ф-ции parse:

```
        try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr))){
            
            String mimeType = tika.detect(is); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
            metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType
            
            AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
            ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc); //разбор файла на части
```

Выводиться такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал выполнить команду:  mvn dependency:tree. Она дала:

```
см. файл по ссылке-https://dropmefiles.com/826tG
```

В некоторых строчках есть надпись "omitted for conflict with". Написано, что происходит конфликт версий, но непонятно на, что надо заменить мои версии библиотек. Подскажите как быть? Может есть еще идеи как решить мою проблему. Заранее спасибо. Буду рад любой мысли на этот счет.

---

Это новый pom.xml, когда привел к одной версии как в ответе. Новый Dependence tree можно увидеть в файле: https://dropmefiles.com/3ZfrF

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackExp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <tika>1.2</tika>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- catch-throwable для отлавливания exception-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.codearte.catch-exception</groupId>
            <artifactId>catch-throwable</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- commons-lang3: для замера времени-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- jdom: для чтения файла task.xml-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tika-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-debugger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ome</groupId>
            <artifactId>bio-formats</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Helper's dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-tika</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
               
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Parser</mainClass>
                       
                       <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                   <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Parser</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
            
            
        </plugins>
    
    </build>
    
  
</project>
```

Comment: Покажите свой maven скрипт

Comment: Не очень понял как это показать скрипт maven, я добавил свой pom.xml, может он поможет натолкнуть на другие мысли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов решения проблемы: после того как привел все библиотеки к одной версии. Убираю повторяющиеся, в моем случае это была tika-app. Далее с помощью команды:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j
```

смотрю какие библиотеки включают slf4j и какую версию они хотят использовать. Посмотрев, можно увидеть конфликт версий. Потому что у меня указан slf4j 1.7.28 в другие библиотеки хотят версию меньше этой.

---

В моей программе главной библиотекой является `org.apache.Tika:tika-app (v1.25)` для нее я ставлю slf4j версией какую она хочет, у меня это 1.7.28. Для других библиотеки прописываю специальные зависимости в pom.xml. Например для `org.tallison:jmatio` из `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j` видно, что у меня есть slf4j 1.7.28, а `jmatio` хочет slf4j 1.7.25:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.tallison:jmatio:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
```

тогда я в pom.xml для него пишу:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tallison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmatio</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Это же проделываю и с другими библиотеками, которые хотят различные версии, отличные от моей slf4j 1.7.28.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать одинаковые версии библиотек, например:

```
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
```

отличается от:

```
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
```

Или:

```
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.26</version>
```

отличается от:

```
        <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
        <version>1.25</version>
```

Всего по тексту скрипта много таких. Приведите всех к одному знаменателю.

Comment: Я изменил старый pom на новый, посмотрите пожалуйста. Я изменил версию slf4j-simple на 1.7.25, slf4j-api - 1.7.25. tika-core-1.7.25, tika - 1.7.25. Попробовал, все также происходит ошибка. Подскажите я все правильно сделал? Некоторые версии других библиотек хотят старые версии slf4j,  как я могу их дать им? Этим библиотекам не нравится моя версия 1.7.25.

Comment: 1) У вас еще `pdfbox`  и `org.osgi` разные версии - их тоже поправьте
2) Покажите диагностику кто и как ругается на версию `slf4j`

Comment: запустите `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j` - он покажет какие либы и какие версии `slf4j` используют